# How is this Clemmensen Reduction taking place?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, metal, organic-reduction, isotope

How did that isotopically labelled Carbon migrate? I know that an carbanion is formed, but I am not able to conclude the final product. Please Help
[image]

Comment: The carbanion formed at one aldehyde attacks the other aldehyde by performing nucleophilic addition to form a cyclopropane ring. This ring opens up in such a way to give a more stable carbanion, which here is going to be on the C14 carbon (because of the electronic effects of oxygen).

Comment: Can you kindly show mechanism like written sort of or text picturised solution

Comment: And how can u compare carbanion stability it is identical

Comment: See the mechanism for clemensen reduction.